# In Imagick, how can I extend the last column pixel and duplicate it horizontally to the size I want?

Tags: imagick

I'm not sure if my subject line is clear enough.

I have an image of a mannequin on a gradient gray background. Thousands actually. Every background is a bit different due to lighting differences etc...

I would like to take these 800pixel wide by 1500pixel tall images and convert them to 1000x1500 by duplicating the first column 1pixel wide by 100 extra pixels and the same to the last column. That way, I can have a smooth gradient across the image and finish with a 1000x1500 pixel image.

I can't figure out how to do it, though. I saw that I can add other images on, or choose a solid color, but since the backgrounds differ, it has to be on a per-image basis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it means I have to use another php solution.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with code!

```
<?php
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath("../images/TestImage.jpg"));

$imagick->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_EDGE);

$desiredWidth = 1000;
$desiredHeight = 1500;

$originalWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();

//Make the image be the desired width.
$imagick->sampleimage(
    $desiredWidth, 
    $imagick->getImageHeight()
);

//Now scale, rotate, translate (aka affine project) it
//to be how you want
$points = array(
    //The x scaling factor is 0.5 when the desired width is double
    //the source width
    ($originalWidth / $desiredWidth), 0,
    //Don't scale vertically
    0, 1,
    //Offset the image so that it's in the centre
    ($desiredWidth - $originalWidth) / 2,  0
);

$imagick->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_AFFINEPROJECTION, $points, false);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();


//Fyi it may be easier to think of the affine transform by 
//how it works for a rotation:
//$affineRotate = array(
//    "sx" => cos($angle),
//    "sy" => cos($angle),
//    "rx" => sin($angle),
//    "ry" => -sin($angle),
//    "tx" => 0,
//    "ty" => 0,
//);
```

Comment: btw this will possibly still look terrible. You'll probably need to blur or possible blend the repeated bit as it's pretty obvious on my test image where the lines repeat.